# How can I deploy Ultralytics YOLOv8 on Azure AKS Specifically on the score.py file?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, yolov8

I am trying to figure out a method to deploy my yolov8 model through an AKS endpoint, but the score.py file keeps failing from my end.

This is the expected response

response = { 'imgBase64' : jpg_as_text, 'predictions':[{"Probability":0.0,"Tagld":0,"TagName":str(prediction),"BoundingBox":{"Left":0.0,"Top":0.0,"Width":0.0,"Height":0.0}}], 'created': datetime.utcnow().isoformat(), 'proc_time': duration} # print(response) return response

Requesting your assistance with the score.py script for any basic yolov8 model for object detection.

But I am unable to figure out how it can be done. Can someone assist with the script?